# How to make a fake column with an autoincrement number in a "group by" query

Tags: mysql

I have data in a table like this:

```
 fgid   qty   ntid
 1      100   10
 2      90    10
 6      200   11
 1      80    11
 1      120   12
 6      100   12
 6      30    13
```

And i make query :

```
SELECT fgid, SUM(qty) AS total_qty, COUNT(ntid) AS nt_count FROM sofg 
GROUP BY fgid
```

AND the result is :

```
 fgid   total_qty   nt_count
 1      300         3
 2      90          1
 6      330         3
```

**Then i want to make the result like this** :

```
no    fgid    total_qty   nt_count
1     1       300         3
2     2       90          1
3     6       330         3
```

**How to do that with a query?** where '**no**' is (like) autoincrement number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query.

```
SELECT 
  @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum, 
  t.* 
  FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
  (
   SELECT fgid, SUM(qty) AS total_qty, COUNT(ntid) AS nt_count FROM sofg GROUP BY fgid
  ) t;
```

Comment: Your query work. But when i try to create a VIEW with your query, error warning appears "[err]1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter".

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same as Dhinakaran's answer, but there's no need to put the whole main query into a subquery. There's no difference to his answer appart from maybe being more pleasing to the eye, but please accept Dhinakaran's answer, as he was faster.

```
SELECT 
@rownum:=@rownum + 1 as rownumber,
fgid, 
SUM(qty) AS total_qty, 
COUNT(ntid) AS nt_count 
FROM sofg
, (select @rownum:=0) v 
GROUP BY fgid
```

Comment: (select @rownum:=0) IS a subquery ;-)

Comment: Er, am I missing something? The two are not mutually exclusive. To quote the manual - 'A subquery is a SELECT statement within another statement.'

Comment: Your query work. But when i try to create a VIEW with your query, error warning appears "[err]1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter".